# Execute python3 filename after creating new user and with skeleton folder

Tags: command-line, bash, permissions, python, python3

I am automating a system to create users in python and run a python script through the user. Here is the code I am running along with the error. The root is creating a user and then running the file as root. The folder being copied from skel looks like this /etc/skel/newFolder. username variable is 'newUser'

```
os.system('sudo adduser --disabled-password --gecos "" ' + username)
path = '/home/'+username+'/newFolder' 
path.replace("'", r"\'")

print(subprocess.run("test -e '{}'".format(path), shell=True))
subprocess.run("sudo python3 '{}'".format(path), shell=True)
print(os.path.isfile(path))
```

Error

```
Adding user 'newUser' ...    
Adding new group 'newUser' (1000) ...    
Adding new user 'newUser' (1000) with group `newUser' ...   
Creating home directory `/home/newUser' ...    
Copying files from '/etc/skel' ...    
CompletedProcess(args="test -e '/home/newUser/newFolder'", returncode=1)    
python3: can't open file '/home/newUser/newFolder/pythonFile.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

The return code of 1 means the test said this 'newFolder' copied from skel doesn't exist. And of course python3 cant find the python file. If I go through the terminal and look for this directory, it does exist. Very frustrating please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The entire error I was getting was because of a capitalization error in the file path. YOU ARE JOKING RIGHT. Problem solved.